# Relationship between epistemology and ontology

Tags: epistemology, ontology

In what domain do questions about the nature of knowledge fall epistemology or ontology?
How do you distinguish the two fields?

Comment: What have you found out so far? :)

Comment: There are 2 sentences in the body of this question, the latter of which is in tune with the title question, the former is something else entirely. Which question do you mean to ask? Are you trying to ask about the differences between the two fields, or whether "knowledge" falls under either? Also, why couldn't you simply look this up yourself? In general, asking easy-to-answer questions is not a problem, but really? These are just the definitions of the most basic categories of philosophy, it's like asking on Math.SE "What is addition and subtraction?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually understood what you're trying ask here, but I can  point out that 'questions about the nature of knowledge' ARE epistemological questions *per se*. 'Do you need any ontology to answer epistemological questions?' - I think that's where you are trying to get to. Well, ontology is all about what things are and it seems that in many cases epistemologists do need to do some ontology [and vice-versa]; metaphysicians do loads of epistemology as well. Just a few examples, 'Knowledge and its Limits' and 'Modal Logics as Metaphysics' from Timothy Williamson, 'Formal Epistemology' Von Hendricks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search would have done it, so next time, please don't be lazy.

> [Ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) is the philosophical study of the nature of being, becoming, existence, or reality, as well as the basic categories of being and their relations.
>
> [Epistemology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) is the branch of philosophy concerned with the nature and scope of knowledge and is also referred to as "theory of knowledge". It questions what knowledge is and how it can be acquired, and the extent to which knowledge pertinent to any given subject or entity can be acquired.